# RedBeanPHP is not storing a bean with html entity

Tags: php, redbean

If I type `rsquo;` into a textarea and it gets saved via `R::store()` it saves it to the database.

If I edit this post it shows `'` and if I hit save RedBean will strip the quotation and store the empty bean.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Encode it before you give it back to `R::store()`.** See [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

However, if you never called `html_entity_decode` yourself, my guess is that you've made some error elsewhere and that your `'` is the result of that error.